# Python dicts, take a dictionary and return a dict where the keys are one of the values from the former dict and the values are the keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to write a function that takes the dictionary:

```
sites = {
   42: ("Christchurch", "Canterbury"),
 8472: ("Timaru", "Canterbury"),
   11: ("Westport", "Westland")
}
```

An returns:

```
{'Canterbury': [42, 8472], 'Westland': [11]}
```

I currently have:

```
sites_dict = {}
for site_id, site in sites_info.items():
    city, region = site
    sites_dict[region] = [site_id]
    if region in sites_dict:
        site_id = [site_id]
```

Which only returns replaces the values each time it loops.
Thanks.

Comment: What happened to Westport and Timaru?

Comment: @DaniMesejo, It looks the value is tuple (city, region) and they just want the region as key.

Comment: I dont need either of them in the new dict. Only that Christchurch, Timaru share one of the same values from a tuple, their region so I am to gather their keys.

Comment: Currently my function returns {'Canterbury': [8472], 'Westland': [11]}

Answer (score 0):

Use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

sites = {
   42: ("Christchurch", "Canterbury"),
 8472: ("Timaru", "Canterbury"),
   11: ("Westport", "Westland")
}

result = defaultdict(list)
for key, (_, site) in sites.items():
    result[site].append(key)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Canterbury': [42, 8472], 'Westland': [11]})
```

Or using a simple dictionary:

```
result = {}
for key, (_, site) in sites.items():
    if site not in result:
        result[site] = []
    result[site].append(key)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'Canterbury': [42, 8472], 'Westland': [11]}
```